Related to Document Intelligence - Azure Cognitive Services
I have built a composed model in document intelligence studio(Formerly known as Form recognizer). It is built to extract different fields from different types of document with different patterns.
There is no problem when the composed model is fed with document type with which it is train. But when I fed a  new document with unknown pattern(not trained with this pattern), still it extracts the fields and I cannot even apply a filter for confidence score of the extracted fields as well because for some extracted field, the confidence score is more than 90%.
I tried to apply the classification model as well but even that is not working.
So, I need help for how can I get a response or handle this condition when an unknown document type is fed into the model.

Please provide the filter, index, and indexer configurations in text or JSON format. Also, share any relevant links you've referred to and the code you've tried in a text format.

Hey Sampath, thank you for your reply.
I came up with a solution.
I am using composed model and so it returns the docType inside the documents in the response.
"documents": [
{
"docType": "model-composed-1:model-doc1-en-1"
}
.....
]
When a doc gets extracted by this model type "model-doc1-en-1",  I am expecting some content which is specifically in that particular doc type only. So when I am uploading a unknown document the content will be extracted but the expected content in that particular document will not be present and it will be filtered.

thank you for your reply. I came up with a solution. I am using composed model and so it returns the docType inside the documents in the response.
"documents": [ 
       { 
           "docType": "model-composed-1:model-doc1-en-1" 
        } 
        ..... ] 

When a doc gets extracted by this model type "model-doc1-en-1", I am expecting some content which is specifically in that particular doc type only. So when I am uploading a unknown document the content will be extracted but the expected content in that particular document will not be present and it will be filtered.
